# SMS my contact for ease of entry

Tags: meteor

A Meteor app is being used to add customer details to a database. I want to send a SMS to the customer. The SMS need to include my business name, address, mobile number in such a way so that he will not need to re type in his contacts list.

I have SMS gateway in place and can send SMS to customers, but not sure how to do it in such a way that the customer does not have to re type my contacts in his phone. Any suggestions where to start so that the recipient can just save what I sent him and all goes in a new contact on his phone with the info I already sent in the SMS? Thanks

Comment: [This](https://atmospherejs.com/dispatch/accounts-sms) packages leverages twilio. That could be your starting point?

Comment: Don't you want to send a vCard instead of a plain text message?